# reopen sign in dialog to connect with google fit

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I'm developing an app that uses google fit to collect the burned calories. To connect with google fit the user needs to connect with their google account. 
Therefore, a dialog is opening:
[image]
BUT: When clicking anywhere but not on the dialog, the dialog dissappears and google fit is not connected.

That's fine. BUT I have a button. When clicking on the button and google fit is not connected yet the dialog shall be visible again. 
But I don't know how to do that. I already tried using the Account Picker Dialog, but then google fit is not connecting either.

My Code:

```
private void buildFitnessClient() {
    // Create the Google API Client
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(AppIndex.API)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ))  //for height and weight
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ_WRITE))//for height and weight
            .addConnectionCallbacks(
                    new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                            android.util.Log.i(TAG, "Connected!!!");
                            // Now you can make calls to the Fitness APIs.  What to do?
                            // Look at some data!!
                            isGoogleFitConnected = true;

                            new read_google_fit_data_task(MainActivity.this, client).execute();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                            // If your connection to the sensor gets lost at some point,
                            // you'll be able to determine the reason and react to it here.
                            if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                android.util.Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
                            } else if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                android.util.Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
                            }
                        }
                    }
            )
            .enableAutoManage(this, 0, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

                    if (!authInProgress) {
                        try {
                            authInProgress = true;
                            result.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, ConnectionResult.CANCELED);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.e("GoogleFit", "authInProgress");
                    }
                }
            })
            .build();
}
```

However, when I'm closing my app and restarting it, the dialog is appearing again and it is possible to connect with google fit.

Does anyone may know the answer? I would be very pleased!

Comment: Does nobody know an answer yet?

Comment: You need to call log out first from GoogleApiClient only then google will ask for new account or you can get all integrated account first and then login GoogleApiClient with the selected account